# How to match the start or end of a string with string.match in Lua?

Tags: lua

I am using this to match the text which appears between two words:

```
a1 = "apple"
a2 = "bear"
match_pattern = string.format('%s(.*)%s', a1, a2)
str = string.match(str, match_pattern)
```

How can I make a match between the start of the string and a number or a number and the end of the string?

Comment: -1: for the answer being easily findable in [the documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1)

Comment: Sheesh, people are hard on others here.  'RTFM' seems like the opposite of the spirit of the site. The lua documentation may be easy to search, but it's hard to understand. I wish I could answer the question myself, but having already found the documentation impenetrable I've come here searching for answers too. Good luck!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> match between the start of the string and a number or a number and the end of the string?

`^` at the start of a pattern anchors it to the start of the string.
`$` at the end of a pattern anchors it to the end of the string.

```
s = 'The number 777 is in the middle.'

print(s:match('^(.*)777')) --> 'The number '
print(s:match('777(.*)$')) --> ' is in the middle.'
```

or to match any number:

```
print(s:match('^(.-)%d+')) --> 'The number '
print(s:match('%d+(.*)$')) --> ' is in the middle.'
```

The first pattern changes slightly to use a non-greedy match, which will match as few characters as possible. If we'd used `.*` rather than `.-`, we would have matched `The number 77`.