# What's the Lua equivalent of Python's endswith()?

Tags: lua, nmap

I want to convert this Python code to Lua (`nmap` script):

```py
for i in range(1000, 9999):
    if str(i).endswith('9'):
        print(i)
```

I've come this far:

```lua
for var = 1000, 9000 then
    if tostring(var).endswith('9') then
        print (var)
    end
end
```

but I don't know the Lua equivalent of `endswith()`.

Comment: There isn't one, I think. You can write one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match the start or end of a string with string.match in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159817/how-to-match-the-start-or-end-of-a-string-with-string-match-in-lua)

Comment: Karl Knechtel: Not really - `string.match` is only one approach that can be taken here.

Answer (score 7):

### XY-Problem

The X problem of how to best port your code to Lua has been answered by quantumpro already, who optimized it & cleaned it up.

I'll focus on your Y problem:

> What's the Lua equivalent of Python `endswith`?

### Calling string functions, OOP-style

In Lua, strings have a metatable that indexes the global `string` library table. String functions are called using `str:func(...)` in Lua rather than `str.func(...)` to pass the string `str` as first "self" argument (see ["Difference between `.` and `:` in Lua"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911186/difference-between-and-in-lua)).

Furthermore, if the argument to the call is a single string, you can omit the parentheses, turning `str:func("...")` into `str:func"..."`.

### Constant suffix: Pattern Matching

Lua provides a more powerful pattern matching function that can be used to check whether a string ends with a suffix: [`string.match`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.match). `str.endswith("9")` in Python is equivalent to `str:match"9$"` in Lua: `$` anchors the pattern at the end of the string and `9` matches the literal character `9`.

Be careful though: This approach doesn't work with arbitrary, possibly variable suffices since certain characters - such as `$` - are *magic characters* in Lua patterns and thus have a special meaning. Consider `str.endswith(".")`; this is not equivalent to `string:match".$"` in Lua, since `.` matches *any* character.

I'd say that this is the lua-esque way of checking whether a string ends with a constant suffix. Note that it *does not return a boolean*, but rather a match (the suffix, a truthy value) if successful or `nil` (a falsey value) if unsuccessful; it can thus safely be used in `if`s. To convert the result into a boolean, you could use `not not string:match"9$"`.

### Variable suffix: Rolling your own

Lua's standard library is very minimalistic; as such, you often need to roll your own functions even for basic things. There are two possible implementations for `endswith`, one using pattern matching and another one using substrings; the latter approach is preferable because it's shorter, possibly faster (Lua uses a naive pattern matching engine) and doesn't have to take care of pattern escaping:

```lua
function string:endswith(suffix)
    return self:sub(-#suffix) == suffix
end
```

Explanation: `self:sub(-#suffix)` returns the last suffix length characters of `self`, the first argument. This is compared against the suffix.

You can then call this function using the colon (`:`) syntax:

```lua
str = "prefixsuffix"
assert(str:endswith"suffix")
assert(not str:endswith"prefix")
```

Answer (score 2):

The python code is not great, you can get the last digit by using modulo `%`

```py
# python code using modulo
for i in range(1000,9999):
    if i % 10 == 9:
        print(i)
```

This also works in Lua. However Lua includes the last number in the loop, unlike python.

```lua
-- lua code to do this
for i=1000, 9998 do
    if i % 10 == 9 then
        print(i)
    end
end
```

However in both languages you could iterate by 10 each time

```py
for i in range(1009, 9999, 10):
    print(i)
```

```lua
for i=9, 9998, 10 do
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for var = 1000, 9000 do
  if string.sub(var, -1) == "9" then
     -- do your stuff
  end
end
```